# Would it be possible to create a zero knowledge social network?

Tags: encryption

I understand the concept behind a zero knowledge web application where only the user has access to their data. What about a social network where some circles of user have access to that data?

Is it possible to have multiple public keys decrypt a "friends" information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst multiple public keys for a single private key [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19148806/2805324), it is not recommended.

In practice this sort of problem is solved by abstracting the private key exponent into a single symmetrical session key encrypted by as many multiple asymmetric key pairs as needed.

For instance, for a secure social network, each post you publish to the cloud is encrypted by a symmetrical session key which in turn is encrypted with public keys of everyone currently belonging to the social circle that you have posted the message to.

Revocation of friends from a circle is trivial, in that you don't encrypt the next session key with that person's public key.

Revocation of access to data that they have already seen is *not* trivial as data propagates freely across the internet once any authorised party has decrypted and disseminated it. Basic social networking common sense applies in this scenario.

We currently rely on a Netscape PKI design kludge from the early 90s for the world's internet security. So I wouldn't worry about whether key distribution uses classic PKI. For a client-server secure social network, the server could act as an OAuth/OpenID server with a public key cache.

Answer (score 1):

No. Existing algorithms used for PKI are one to one. If they were not they would be easier to brute force.

The way to achieve this would not be to have multiple public keys, but to encrypt the data with the public key and then have the application share the private key with your circle of friends.

The problem is how you get the keys to your group of friends. And what to do if one of said friends becomes an ex-friend.